# If an observable is in progress, subscribe to it, if not, start it again

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

If I have an observable that takes a long time to execute. We will call it `longObservable` which is of type Observable, takes 5 seconds to execute, and each time it executes it emits a new string only once then completes.

```
longObservable(): Subject<string> {
    return timer(5000).pipe{
        map(() => randomString())
    }
}
```

And some other pages call it multiple times. If it's in process, I'd like to just continue that one process. If it's complete, I'd like to start it again.

```
longObservable.subscribe() // Immediate, start the timer
```

and this runs two seconds later:

```
longObservable.subscribe() // Get the same string as
                            //  the above subscription in 3 seconds.
```

and this runs 20 seconds later

```
longObservable.subscribe() // Start a new iteration and wait
                            // 5 seconds, get a new string.
```

The second subscribe I think is easy, it'll work how I want. It's the 3rd one that I'm having trouble with. It will emit the same value as the other two immediately since `longObservable` is complete.

This is being used for geolocation on a device. I want to request a new location, but if there is already a request in progress, just use that result.

Edit: Changed observable to subject for multicasting, removed take(1).

Edit2: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-venpk4 here is a working example of what I want. I'm hoping to accomplish this without the timerRunning variable and with RxJS operators. It's under the hello component and prints to the console.

Comment: Your question seems confusing

Comment: note: `take(1)` in your example is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky problem.  Here is my solution in a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-so-q-54136646?file=index.ts).  A couple of keys to this are the `share()` operator, which effectively turns the observable into a subject, without having to declare the subject explicitly.  However, you need a NEW subject to be created with a new subscription once the old one completes, so I created a factory function to either return the existing sharable Observable (if `longObservable()` is still in progress) or else generate a new one.

Here are the important bits from the StackBlitz:

```
let inProgress: boolean = false;

function longObservable(): Observable<string> {
    return timer(5000).pipe(
        map(() => randomString()),
        tap(() => inProgress = false),
        share()
    )
}

let obs$: Observable<string>;

function getLongObs(): Observable<string> {
    if (inProgress) {
        return obs$
    } else {
        inProgress = true;
        obs$ = longObservable();
        return obs$;
    }
}

console.log('initiate first subscribe');
getLongObs().subscribe(
    rand => console.log(`First subscribe returned ${rand}`)
);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('initiate second subscribe');
    getLongObs().subscribe(
        rand => console.log(`Second subscribe returned ${rand}`)
    );
}, 2000);

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('initiate third subscribe');
    getLongObs().subscribe(
        rand => console.log(`Third subscribe returned ${rand}`)
    );
}, 7000)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I simplified this significantly in the StackBlitz.  Ended up very similar to what @Kyle had when all was said and done.  :)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I ended up using some public variable to track states, but this would have done the job.

Comment: Glad it helped!  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is the `share()` pipe. Something like this works:

```js
    export class AppComponent {
        private _longObservable: Observable<string> = null

        constructor() {
            this._longObservable = timer(5000).pipe(
                // This will show us when timer emits a value which will prove that the
                // first two subscriptions below are sharing the same "execution"
                // of the observable.
                tap(() => console.log("Timer Triggered!")), 
                map(() => randomString()),
                share()
            );
        }

        ngOnInit() {
            // These two will share the observable,
            // since long observable hasn't completed by the time the second
            // subscription is triggered.
            this._longObservable.subscribe(console.log);
            setTimeout(() => this._longObservable.subscribe(console.log), 2000);

            // This subscription occurs after the 5 sec.
            // Since timer is a cold observable, this will trigger it to run again.
            setTimeout(() => this._longObservable.subscribe(console.log), 7000);
        }


    }
```

Output:

```
Timer Triggered!
randomString1
randomString1
Timer Triggered!
randomString2
```

Here is an article on the difference between hot and cold observables if you aren't familiar with that distinction: https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339

Http requests in angular, and `timer(5000)` are both cold observables.

Here is a link to some info about the share pipe: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html

Answer (score 1):

As you show in your example, your method returns new Observable instance, which creates every time you subscribe to it. I think in your service you can create a property, which will store your observable. May be better to make this property as BehaviorSubject. And wherever you want you can subscribe to this property. So every subscriprion will be to the same Observable instance.

Comment: So after I do that, which I've done, how do I make the 3rd subscription act the way I want it to? It will emit the previous value from the 5 second timer. I want it to start a new 5 second timer and get a new value (only after the 1st has happened). I still want the first two subscriptions to act the same way.

Comment: As I understand you correctly, 1st and 2nd subscription must be subscribed at the same stream, but 3rd must create new stream. If I`m right, multicasting helps you https://angular.io/guide/observables#multicasting

Comment: The multicasting solved it that my first and second subscriptions get the same value. But how do I get it to re-run the timer only if the currently running timer is complete for my 3rd subscription example? Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I guess to be more clear, I'm getting the user's location. If there is already a request going out to get his location, I want it to just return that result. But if it already went out and completed, I want to get the user's location again.

Comment: Could you show an example at https://stackblitz.com/ ? It will be much easier to understand your question.

Comment: After reading your expectation - "I'm hoping to accomplish this without the timerRunning variable and with RxJS operators." - I think an example of multicasting in https://angular.io/guide/observables#multicasting is suitable for you. I mean you should use some field which store your state

Comment: Yah that's what I ended up doing. Was hoping to avoid that, not sure why.